# pdf.js: PDF file from servlet which requires a variable

Tags: java, servlets, pdf.js

I am using `pdf.js` to view PDF files in my GWT application. I've implemented the viewer exactly as the product of a build operation as described on the [readme](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/README.md).

When I use the viewer with a static pdf, this works fine. When I supply the link to a servlet that serves the pdf however, the pdf viewer doesn't load.

**Works fine**

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://127.0.0.1:8888/staticpdf.pdf`

**Doesn't work**

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/getPdf?nodeRef=001`

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/getPdf?nodeRef=001` yields a pdf file. The servlet has always worked.

This won't work, because `pdf.js#getDocument` proceeds to make a GET call without parameters, while the servlet needs the nodeRef:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/getPdf?nodeRef
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 0
```

**How would I implement the java servlet and `pdf.js` to be able to view a PDF file given a certain nodeRef?** (only the servlet knows how to turn nodeRef into PDF, I need the path to the PDF to remain hidden)

I've been thinking along the lines of `api/getPdf/001`, but have no idea how to catch this on the tomcat server, and if that is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was thinking too much within `pdf.js` I had been tinkering with it for hours, and even this question itself has changed a dozen times because I kept finding new leads.

However, I've now found a simple solution.

- Instead of accessing my servlet as `/getPdf?nodeRef=001`, I access it `/getPdf/001`
- My servlet mapping is now `/getPdf/*`

The servlet contains the following new code in doGet:

```
String nodeRef = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
```

This omits the need for basic `GET` parameters in the url, at least in the format `?a=1&b=2`, and works fine to pass a variable to a servlet that returns a PDF file using `pdf.js`.

EDIT: I have editted my question title to reflect the situation so that those who stumble upon this problem too may find their answer here.

Comment: good job.  be sure to select your own answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks :). I will when SO allows me in 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your server mapping, you should encode your URL (with encodeURIComponent, for example):

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/getPdf?nodeRef=001` will turn into `http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8888%2Fapi%2FgetPdf%3FnodeRef%3D001` and pdf.js will handle it correctly as 'file' parameter value.

Cheers!